# Double screen: desktops "moving" with the mouse

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, multi-monitor

I am running Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca, with Cinnamon 2.4.5.
I have a double screen: my laptop's¹ screen, and another (Dell) screen, both with resolution 1920×1080. I have a strange bug (maybe is it a feature, that I do not know how to deactivate!), and I have difficulties to explain it, so please tell me if you cannot make sense of my explanations.

Let me precise that my external screen is the primary screen, and the laptop screen the secondary screen. Also, the laptop screen is on the right of the external screen. The bug occurs with mouse moves:

1. When I log in, everything is displayed well. The mouse is on the primary screen.
2. I move the mouse to the right on the external screen, up to the frontier between both screens, everything works well.
3. Then, if I continue to the right (going now to the laptop screen), the laptop screen displays what it should, but the external screens begins to display what is on the laptop screen also. What is displayed on the external screen begins to "slide to the left" (the left part is not visible anymore) and on its right, I see the same thing as the left part of the laptop screen.
4. If I go all the way long to the right of the laptop screen, I end up with two identical screens, both displaying what the laptop is supposed to display.
5. Now if I make the inverse path, going to the left, nothing is going on as long as the mouse is on the laptop screen, and when it attains the external screen, the external screen begins to slide again, to the right this time, to display what it should.
6. When the mouses attains the left edge of the external screen, I am back with the correct display.

I wanted to put here a screenshot, but screenshots are (also...) working strangely, it is probably related.

Do you have any clues?

¹ Dell Precision M4700

Comment: Remove `screen` tag. It's for GNU Screen terminal multiplexer.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I am not having the issue anymore. I am not sure how it disappeared. I do think the bug was removed by some update in Cinnamon some time ago. If your system is not up-to-date, I urge you to update to see if the bug is removed. (Since I changed my laptop a few weeks ago, I cannot perform tests anymore.)

Comment: I've got this occurring with Mint 17.3. I have two cards, on board and a NVidia - one display connected to each. If anyone figures this out...

Answer (score 10):

This just happened to me. The solution: Hold down the ALT key and roll the mouse wheel.  It was a zoom feature that accidentally got triggered when I held down ALT and didn't notice I moved my wheel.

I hope this helps people. It was nuts until I figured it out.

Comment: thanks so much for this answer. it was driving me nuts too.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in Linux Mint 18 Sara,

I hooked up my New build computer initially to my 1080i HD TV and didn't have problems until installing steam. suddenly my desktop no longer fit in my TV screen.  My desktop was bigger than my TV and my mouse would adjust the screen left to right and top to bottom as i moved it. I spent an entire evening trying to figure this out until I was so angry i was ready to go back to windows. **It was like I was zoomed in?**

I believe in giving credit where it is due I The next morning while at work my wife called me and told me she fixed it, and I said thank you followed with how? I hope this simple fix helps someone out their like me who forgets to start with the simple solutions instead of diving straight into the terminal or checking drivers and graphic card settings.

My wife fixed the problem by going to - MENU - Preferences - ACCESSIBILITY -

Then she turned **ZOOM OFF**

Comment: I didn't have the original problem, but your answer popped up on a google search, and the solution wasn't in that menu but using Alt + mouse wheel, as described at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266999&p=13235719#post13235719 - so it's definitely off-topic, but it could help someone else who stumbles upon it

Comment: I know this is old, but I've just had the same issue in i3 (manjaro). There are no menus or preferances or accessibility options. does anyone know what config file/command I need to change to disable this?

Comment: thanks! this randomly happened to me could not figure it out till i found your post :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on ubuntu with gnome 3, it was fixed with using new drivers of nvidia (375.20)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPri9.png

Comment: It would be helpful to the OP to understand if you could explain.

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean? "Helpful to OP"
I suppose that this is driver problem and in nvidia drivers 375.20 it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I occaisionally had the same issue on Linux Mint 18 Sarah Cinnamon v3.0.7, with cards on board and an nvidia.

What solved it for me was changing driver from `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` to `nvidia-375` for the nvidia driver in Driver mananger.

Answer (score 0):

Alt + mouse roll up or down to fit the screen

Comment: To fit _what_ to the screen? What screen, the physical or the desktop that is being scrolled around with the movement of the mouse?